# how to avoid mouseExited to fire while on any nested component

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener

**In my code i have:**

an abstract class extending JComponent which contains some JTextFields.
JTextFields aren't editable.
JComponent class implement MouseListener:
- when mouseEntered event fires a border is added to it.
- when mouseExited event fires border is removed.
- when mouseClicked event fires  all fields of that component are set as editable.

**This should work in this way:**

- User want to edit a field.
- He mouseHover any point of the the jComponent
- border is draw on the jComponent  to highlight it
- User click and the mouseClicked method fires which does its stuffs.

**The problem is:**
mouseExited fires when the mouse goes over on any JTextField. 
How would you solve the problem?

What follows is a simple class which will show you a window with a jTextField contained into a panel which implement MouseListener in a way pretty similar to the one described above. Do not take into consideration how it's written, it s just for purpose!

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {       
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run(){   
                int i=0;
                //mainWindow
                    JFrame mainWindow = new JFrame("MyFrame");
                    mainWindow.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                    mainWindow.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200,200));

                    JPanel viewPort = new JPanel();

                    final JTextField text = new JTextField("SOME_RANDOM_TEXT");
                    text.setEditable(false);

                    final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                    panel.add(text);
                    panel.setBackground(Color.green);
                    panel.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                            //NOTHING
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                            //NOTHING
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                            panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                            panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE));
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                            ((JTextField)panel.getComponent(0)).setEditable(true);
                            panel.getComponent(0).requestFocus();
                        }
                    });
                    viewPort.add(panel);
                    mainWindow.add(viewPort,BorderLayout.CENTER);
                    mainWindow.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: great MVCE and formed question :)

Comment: Why is this tagged as SWT?

Comment: @Baz corrected... it's `swing`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the mouse point of the event to determine if the point is still in the bounds of the panel or not:

```
panel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
{
    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
    {
        Rectangle r = e.getComponent().getBounds();
        Point p = e.getPoint();

        if (p.x < 0 || p.x >= r.width
        ||  p.y < 0 || p.y >= r.height)
            panel.setBorder( null );
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
    {
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE));
    }
});
```

It is easier to extend MouseAdapter, then you only need to override the methods you want to customize.

Comment: First of all, thank! It works!, there is just a little bug

Answer (score 2):

Problem is you set the `MouseListener` to the `JPanel`, which does not make much sense (for the desired described behaviour).

Just change the `MouseListener` to `JTextField`:

```
text.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
```

It's working nice for me.

---

**UPDATE**:

> You missed something mate :) Thx for the fast answer, but, my `JPanel` can contains more then a single textField, it could contains for example, 10 of them!

The example is ok as example, but in real life you won't create an inner listener, you will create a class.

```
class MyMouseListener implements MouseListener {
    // define methods and behaviour
}
```

and then you will add it to your selectable areas like:

```
MyMouseListener listener = new MyMouseListener()
panel1.addMouseListener(listener);
panel2.addMouseListener(listener);
panel3.addMouseListener(listener);
```

---

**TIP:** remember [`MouseEvent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html) extends from [`ComponentEvent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ComponentEvent.html) that has a great method [`getComponent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ComponentEvent.html#getComponent())

> Returns the originator of the event.

Comment: You missed something mate :)
Thx for the fast answer, but, my Panel can contains more then a single textField, it could contains for example, 10 of them!

Comment: and? BRO! just don't create an inner listener and add same to all objects ;)

Comment: If i add the listener to all the textFields there would be 2 problem: the minor one is that the border would be Drawn for the textField, and i want it on it's container (this one could be solved by using the "super" by the way). The second problem, is that the border would no be drawn when the mouse is between 2 jtextFields but not hover any of them.
I thought about that, i could add the listener on both container and contained jtextFields, but i was wondering if there is something less expensive in terms of writing/event managment

Comment: please check my update, and if necessary, create a new question with new problems.... please [avoid to modifing your questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)

Comment: just read it, but i didn't get it yet xD sorry about that ^^
I m gonna change my example code so we can both understand each other in a easier way xD

Comment: **DON'T CHANGE YOUR QUESTION** ask a new one please, check the chameleon questions link i provided in previous comment, it's against StackOverflow rules to modify original questions

Comment: i didn't! I changed the given code to properly explain the problem. Check it pls!

Comment: as I told you, the problem now is another, please check my answer, create separated listener class, add it to each component. **Don't hesitate to ask if necessary**, but you didn't used my answer, so please, don't change the questions. [**PLEASE CHECK THIS LINK**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code)

Comment: i think you misunderstud it. Read it once more carefully, and if don't get it i ll try explain again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91614/discussion-between-koop4-and-jordi-castilla).